# Generating combinations algorithmically

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I have an n-high pyramid of numbers like:

```
    1
   5 8
  2 5 4
 8 9 3 1
2 8 3 7 2
```

How can I algorithmically walk through every possible path from the top of the pyramid to the bottom?

To better explain, let me represent the pyramid this way:

```
1 2 3 4 5
-----------
1         | a
5 8       | b
2 5 4     | c
8 9 3 1   | d
2 8 3 7 2 | e
```

For example:

```
        On the path | a b c d e (Path)
       -------------|------------------
Path 1:  1 5 2 8 2  | 1 1 1 1 1
Path 2:  1 5 2 8 8  | 1 1 1 1 2
Path 3:  1 5 2 9 8  | 1 1 1 2 2
Path 4:  1 5 2 9 3  | 1 1 1 2 3
...
Path m:  1 8 4 1 2  | 1 2 3 4 5
```

Where *m* is the total number of paths.

I understand that the problem can be reduced to simply generate all the possible paths denoted in the second column of the table, and I could come up fairly easily with an algorithm to generate those for a 5-high (or any other fixed high) pyramid, but I can't seem to come up with a general solution.

The algorithm cannot be recursive, for the simple reason that I've already solved the problem recursively and I'm interested in a non-recursive solution to get a complete view of the problem.

Comment: This problem is inherently recursive. Even if you cheated by creating your own stack and iterating, you are just shifting the recursion from the call stack to some other data structure that you manage, as opposed to the CPU.

Comment: I think all he wants is a non recursive algorithm without calling the function again. (of course a recursion can always be made non recursive using your own stack)

Comment: No need to be recursive. At each level, you have a position, and the position of the next level can only be (-0.5) or (+0.5) (if you use the isosceles triangle diagram at the top of your post), or { (0) , (1) } (if you use your right-angle triangle diagram that is easier to implement in code).

Comment: In other words, at every node you only have a binary choice: left or right.

Comment: The non-recursive part refers to the fact that [breadth-first search (BFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) can always be re-implemented as non-recursive algorithms by using suitable data structure sto store nodes that are "to be visited later".

Comment: @rwong Thank you for your pointers. I feel like my problem could be solved with simpler data structures, as it is a very special case of binary tree (basically as regular as you can get). I think I've come up with something, I'm going to post it later.

Comment: Jeah, use a binary tree and your have inevitably at a recursive BFS or DFS algorithm which can be implemented with a stack/deque data structure as @rwong pointed.

Comment: Your structure is a graph, not a tree (because it has cycles). What you're asking is trivial. You just traverse the graph, breadth first or depth first and when you reach a leaf you've got a new path. If you're trying to solve a problem, something like finding the number of the possible paths or a path that maximizes the sum of the values along it, then you don't need to generate all the paths to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you start at the top of the triangle there's only 2 choices to continue the path - left or right. If you chose left, then there's only 2 choices to continue the path - left or right. If you chose right, then there's only....

Let's encode the "left or right" decision at each level as 1 bit, where 0 = left and 1 = right. If there are 5 levels you can encode a path as 4 bits. If there are N levels you can encode a path as (N - 1) bits. The number of paths is 1 << (N - 1).

Now let's think about the bottom row. If you always choose "left" then it'd be path 0000b, which has no set bits, and you end up at the 0th number on the bottom row. If you always choose "right" then it'd be path 1111b, which has 4 set bits, and you end up at the 4th number on the bottom row. If you alternate (left, right, left, right) it'd be path 0101b, which has 2 set bits, and you end up at the 2nd number on the bottom row. If you alternate the opposite way (right, left, right, left) it'd be path 1010b, which has 2 set bits, and you end up at the 2nd number on the bottom row. The position of the number on the bottom row depends on how many set bits in the path.

Now think about the second to last row - it's the same as the last row, except you ignore the last bit! Just shift the path number right once, and count the number of set bits to determine the position of the number on the second to last row.

If you think about this; you probably don't even need to bother generating a table of paths in the first place - you could write a `get_number(path, row)` function and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

Make a list `t` of left or right markers (0: left, 1: right) for all levels-1:
So in your example `t` has 4 entries initially all set to zero (marking the first path) through your pyramid (tree).

so now you need to count through all left or right possibilities
at each level (except level 0, which is the first node) we either go right or left :

**Python:**

```
pyr = [
        [1] ,     
        [5 ,8]     ,  
        [2,5, 4]   ,  
        [8, 9, 3, 1]   ,
        [2, 8,3, 7, 2] ]

pyrD = len(pyr)-1

t = [0]*pyrD

def getNodes(t):
      print("---------------")
      print("leftRightIndices: " , t)
      nodesIdx = [0]
      nodes = [ pyr[0][nodesIdx[0]] ]
      for idx,LorR in enumerate(t):
          nodesIdx.append( nodesIdx[idx]+LorR )
          nodes.append(pyr[idx+1][nodesIdx[idx+1]])

      print("nodes: " , nodes)
      print(nodes)


done = False
while not done:

    getNodes(t)

    for i in range(0,pyrD):
        carryOver = (t[i] + 1) > 1
        if not carryOver:
            t[i]+=1
            break;
        else:
            if i == pyrD-1:
                done = True
            t[i] = 0;
```

Which gives:

```
    ---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 0, 0, 0]
nodes:  [1, 5, 2, 8, 2]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 0, 0, 0]
nodes:  [1, 8, 5, 9, 8]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 1, 0, 0]
nodes:  [1, 5, 5, 9, 8]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 1, 0, 0]
nodes:  [1, 8, 4, 3, 3]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 0, 1, 0]
nodes:  [1, 5, 2, 9, 8]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 0, 1, 0]
nodes:  [1, 8, 5, 3, 3]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 1, 1, 0]
nodes:  [1, 5, 5, 3, 3]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 1, 1, 0]
nodes:  [1, 8, 4, 1, 7]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 0, 0, 1]
nodes:  [1, 5, 2, 8, 8]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 0, 0, 1]
nodes:  [1, 8, 5, 9, 3]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 1, 0, 1]
nodes:  [1, 5, 5, 9, 3]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 1, 0, 1]
nodes:  [1, 8, 4, 3, 7]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 0, 1, 1]
nodes:  [1, 5, 2, 9, 3]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 0, 1, 1]
nodes:  [1, 8, 5, 3, 7]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [0, 1, 1, 1]
nodes:  [1, 5, 5, 3, 7]
---------------
leftRightIndices:  [1, 1, 1, 1]
nodes:  [1, 8, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I guess paths with "leaps" are not legal. The path `[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]` for instance has a leap from column 2 to column 0.

Comment: yes, of course, if this is the case? then its a tree!
we could add a leapCheck routine for every solution and discard it :-)

Comment: @Gabriel If you look at my example, you will find that I've discarded the path `1 1 1 2 1`, which contains a leap.

Comment: Jeah you are correct!

Comment: I correct the code, it becomes even simpler, in a moment

Comment: Your new method is very similar to the one I've come up with this morning. I'm going to try to implement it later today.